# Convert .po file to json in Python 2.7

Tags: python, json, django, localization, django-rest-framework

Simple question: I have a django app with django-rest-framework, and I want to make an endpoint that would return a localization file as a json result. This is my API endpoint:

```
def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    lang = pk
    pofile = settings.LOCALE_PATHS[0] + '/' + lang + '/' + 'LC_MESSAGES' + '/' + 'django.po'
    print pofile
```

The `pofile` variable has the correct path to the actual .po file in the application, now I need to read that file and convert it to json. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert PO files to JSON you can use [pojson library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pojson)

Answer (score 0):

This works for python 2.7 and 3.x also

```
import pojson,polib 
po_file_path = polib.pofile(<po_filename>)
po_dict = pojson.po2dict(po_file_path)
print(po_dict)
```